# $_GET not able to save the data in the database

Tags: mysql

I was making a affiliate website and i was trying to append user id in the url and retrieve it with get and save in the db with time that the xyz user clicked at this time.Please Help.Stucked.P.S.all connections db name are correct and working in other queries

```
 <?php require_once("navig.php");
        $cool=$_SESSION['user_id'];

        if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
            ?>
        <form name="form" method="GET" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"> 
        <a href='http://www.amazon.in/?param=<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'] ?>'><img src=images/a.png ></a>
        </form>

        <?php
            require_once('connect.php');
            $dbb = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
                or die('Error communicating to MySQL server.');
                 if(isset($_GET['param'])){

        $querye = "INSERT INTO orderdata(user_id, store_used) ".
                                "VALUES ('$_GET['param']', 'amazon')";
        mysqli_query ($dbb, $querye);                       
        mysqli_close($dbb);     
        }               
        }
            ?>
```

Comment: What is the actual problem? Are you getting an error message? What is it?

Comment: Data is not getting saved in the database,there is no error

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a request to http://www.amazon.in/.

Replace that with your own development enviroment. Eg.: http://localhost/

Comment: N how does that improves the situation?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is '$_GET['param']' you are using a single quote inside a single quote try to use double quote instead of single or use it without any quotes like '$_GET[param]'

Comment: Alternatively, `VALUES ({$_GET['param']}, 'amazon')`